# About adjoint operators on spaces without inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, adjoint-operators

This is the following definition we are using for Adjoing Operator on normed vectorial spaces:

Let $A \in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$, the adjoint of $A$ is the only bounded operator  $A^*:F^* \rightarrow E^*$ s.t,

\begin{equation}g(Ax) = (A^*g)(x)  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x\in E, \ \forall 
 g\in F^*.\end{equation}

And with this definition we wouldn't need any inner product, but when trying to find adjoint of operators I'm finding trouble, both with finding its adjoint and to understand this equivalence with spaces with inner product.

Example:

1) $A:L^2([0,1])\rightarrow L^2([0,1])$, $A_x(t) = \int_{0}^{t} x(s) ds$

Using inner product we have

\begin{equation} <g,Ax> = \int_0^1 g(t)\int_0^t x(s) ds \ dt = \int_0^1 x(s) \int_s^1 g(t) dt \ ds = <A^*g,x>  \end{equation}
giving us, $A^*g (s) = \int_s^1 g$,  but i can't compute this operator without using this inner product and going via the definition i have (as composition), and I'm having trouble understanding how they would be equivalent, but in this case it's okay as I have an inner product to rely on (even the exercise should be solved without it as far as i know).

2)$A: l^1(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow l^1(\mathbb{N})$, $A_x =(x_1, ... ,x_n, 0,0,0,...)$ with fixed n,

in this case if i were to use the $l^2$ inner product i would have 
\begin{equation} <g,Ax> = \sum y_i x_i = <A^*g,x> \end{equation}
and then $A$ would be self adjoint, but here i can't even tell if this is correct as I'm "borrowing" the inner product.

Any help to clarify these ideas would be apreciated!

Comment: Hint: Try translating inner products into members of dual spaces and see if you can formulate a definition of adjoint for banach spaces.

Comment: @Wraith1995 i don't quite get it, the problem is we haven't been introduced to inner products yet.

Comment: Okay @Daniel Moraes. I will provide the key fact, but there are many references on inner products/Hilbert spaces that you should consult (e.g Royden's functional analysis). The key fact is that any bounded functional, $g$, on a Hilbert space $H$ can be written as $g(x) = <y,x>$ for some $y\in H$.